# Update/merge data instead of replacing it with PUT method in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, put

In a Django app (that uses DRF), I have a user profile model. To update the profile info, I want to use PUT. However, I have a field called "meta", that is an object/dict itself. If I am missing any of its properties (gender, mobile, birthday), I will lose that data since the whole "meta" is replaced with the new one. That does not happen with any of the fields (e.g., if I do not specify the first name, the field will just stay the same). Here's an example of a PUT request body:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "email": "jane@example.com",
    "meta": {
        "gender": "female",
        "mobile": 123456789,
        "birthday":"01-01-1970"
    }
}
```

What can I do to assure that the missing properties are not lost? Is there a way to implement or force a merge/update of the previous data with the one in the request?

Here's the method:

```
    def put(self, request, pk):
        user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And here's the serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'url',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'meta'
        ]
```

Comment: can you add the `UserSerializer` ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`update(...)`** method of the serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'url',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'meta'
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance_meta = instance.meta.copy()
        instance_meta.update(validated_data.get("meta", {}))
        validated_data["meta"] = instance_meta
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar. Your solution worked like a charm! Thank you so much!!